# how to move multiple objects in JPanel

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, transform, graphics2d

I want to create multiple squares that move independently and at the same time,and I think the most efficient way is through the transform method in Graphics2D,but I'm not sure how to make it work for each square.I want the square object to be self contained and create its own transforms(instance transforms). Here's what I have so far.

TransformPanel

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TranformPanel extends JPanel {
    private int[] xcoords = {250,248,253,255,249}; 
    private int[] ycoords = {250,253,249,245,250}; 
    private double randomx = 0; 
    private double randomy = 0;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    { 
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        drawTransform(g,randomx,randomy);
    } 
    private void drawTransform(Graphics g,double randomx,double randomy) 
    {  
        Random rn = new Random(); 
        int xnum = rn.nextInt(10)-5; 
        randomx = xnum; 
        int ynum = rn.nextInt(10)-5; 
        randomy = ynum;

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(250,250,10,10);  
        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();   
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;   

        transform.translate(randomx,randomy);
        g2d.draw(transform.createTransformedShape(rect));  

        }
    }
```

TransformDraw

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TransformDraw{ 
    private static TranformPanel panel = new TranformPanel();
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        // Setup our JFrame details 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Transform Polygon Example");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());   
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel); 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) 
        { 
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            frame.repaint(); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Thanks is Advance!

Comment: Create a class which knows where a single box is, use this to paint said box when you need to

Comment: MadProgrammer- Please elaborate on that.How would I track a box's location and would I need to create an object of that class for each box?Also,how would I then transform its location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating something that can manage it's location (and other properties) and which can be "painted"

```
public interface Box {
    public void update(Dimension size);
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d);
}
```

So, this is pretty basic, all it can do is be updated (within a given area) and be painted.  You could expose other properties (like it's bounding box for example) based on your particular needs

Next, we need a simple implementation, something like...

```
public class DefaultBox implements Box {

    private Color color;
    private Rectangle bounds;

    private int xDelta;
    private int yDelta;

    public DefaultBox(Color color, Dimension size) {
        this.color = color;
        bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), size);

        xDelta = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        yDelta = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Dimension size) {
        bounds.x += xDelta;
        bounds.y += yDelta;

        if (bounds.x < 0) {
            bounds.x = 0;
            xDelta *= -1;
        } else if (bounds.x + bounds.width > size.width) {
            bounds.x = size.width - bounds.width;
            xDelta *= -1;
        }
        if (bounds.y < 0) {
            bounds.y = 0;
            yDelta *= -1;
        } else if (bounds.y + bounds.height > size.height) {
            bounds.y = size.height - bounds.height;
            yDelta *= -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.fill(bounds);
    }

}
```

Now, this maintains a simple `Rectangle` instance, which describes the location and size of the object, it also maintains properties about the color and it's speed.

When `update` is called, it updates it's location and does some simple bounds checking to make sure that the box remains within the specified area.

When `paint` is called, it simply paints itself.

Finally, we need some way to update and paint these boxes....

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private List<Box> boxes;
    private Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GREEN, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW};

    public TestPane() {
        boxes = new ArrayList<>(25);
        for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
            Color color = colors[(int) (Math.random() * colors.length)];
            int width = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * 9);
            int height = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * 9);
            boxes.add(new DefaultBox(color, new Dimension(width, height)));
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (Box box : boxes) {
                    box.update(getSize());
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Box box : boxes) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            box.paint(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Okay, so again, this is pretty simple.  It maintains a `List` of `Box`'s, a Swing `Timer` to periodically update the `List` of `Box`'s, calling their `update` method.  The `Timer` the simply calls `repaint`, which (in a round about way) ends up calling `paintComponent`, which then just calls `paint` on each instance of `Box`.

100 boxes...

[image: 100 Boxes]

Comment: Thanks for elaborating.I copy and pasted the code in,but it doesn't fit the launch parameters of Ecplise.Any solution?

Comment: I have no idea what *"but it doesn't fit the launch parameters of Ecplise"* means, I don't use Eclipse.  The code will compile and run from the command line just fine, there's noting special about the code

Comment: Don't worry about it. I'm just stupid and forgot to actually create the TestPanel object in a different java file >.<

Comment: Welcome to my world :P